# Issues compiling XMLFoundation

Tags: c++, qt

I have downloaded the source for [XMLFoundation](https://github.com/BrianAberle/XMLFoundation). I am trying to compile the source, and cannot do it. I get error after error.

I have created a project to compile the source, and I keep getting unresolved external symbol issues with some of the virtual functions.

any help would be great.

(I have windows 7, using QT and the mingw32.)

Comment: If you need help, you should provide error messages, logs, your sample project etc. Saying: "It does not work" is not enough.

Comment: I created a clean VS 2013 project and added all the src files there. QT was not linking the header/cpp folder structure.